# JavaScript/jQuery insert ASP.NET MVC ViewUserControl into form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have existing ASP.NET MVC View pages and View user controls which I currently use in normal straightforward ASP.NET MVC fashion, sometimes I use RenderPartialView or RenderAction, etc.
By themselves they include  tag. I would like to dynamically load either Views or ViewUserControl based on the selection in a dropdown list.

I'm having trouble deciding should I remove  from Views and controls and put it just into the one View that will do dynamic rendering  or to leave it there and leave  outside of the .

What do you think and how would you go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery to get the HTML from your Partial views and substitute it in the div. It could be something like this:

```
$.get('/Controller/Action',function(data){
   $('div').innerHtml(data); 
});
```

I did it this way and it works. `/Controller/Action` can be a partial view which returns HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably try to load the contents of a `div` after doing an AJAX call to get the contents. See the [AJAX get](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype) call in the jQuery docs.

---

Or are the possibilities of what control to load so small you could just hide/show `div`'s that are already in the page?